# How to store user input of one character into EACH element of an array in C++?

Tags: c++

I want the user to input just one character, say 'Y', then I want Y to be stored in each element of an array (ie: array[9]) so that when I print it would be like 'YYYYYYYYY', or when it's a 2d array (ie: array[2][2]) it would look like:

```
YYY
YYY
YYY
```

Comment: Storing and printing are two different problems; so which one are you having problem with and what did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) from `<cstring>`, or [std::fill()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) from `<algorithm>`. So for a `char array[9];`, you can do:

```
memset(array, 'Y', 9);
```

or:

```
std::fill(array, array + 9, 'Y');
```

For a 2D array, you'd set each row individually.

Watch out when using memset(), because the length is given in bytes, not in elements. If you had an `int` array, for example, `memset(array, 'Y', 9)` wouldn't work. std::fill() does not have that problem.

Comment: I don't think this: `memset(array, 'Y', 9 * sizeof(int));` is going to do what you may want. The byte value for an ASCII `'Y'` is `0x59`, for a system with 32-bit integers your `int` values will become `0x59595959`, or 1499027801. You'd definitely want to use `std::fill()` as the correct alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print each entered character same number of times, why to store all? it will waste memory, just store one character and it print any number of times needed, so a single array will be enough,i guess. But this solution is what i got from your question, if there are some constraints please do share or better share code...